# jackrabbit session.importXML() does not honour uuid

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I have been trying to import xml data in to JCR using

```
session.importXML("/", resource, ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_COLLISION_THROW);
```

First time it works fine, but when I do the import the same data again it does not not throw exception even though the uids in the xml are the same. It just adds the records to the database. That means my records keep adding to the database every time I import

It throws exception if I import the xml twice in the same session. If I import the xml in different sessions it does not throw exception. I did some debugging in to the jackrabbit code.  At the time of importing the data from xml jackrabbit goes through each record and it if it has unique id then it tries to find whether the record already exists, apparently it does not find even though that is there. It finds it if the record already imported in the same session.

Here is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sv:node xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
     xmlns:pb="http://pb.com/pb/hubble/projects/1.0/"
     xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0"
     sv:name="Viewpoint">
<sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
    <sv:value>pb:component</sv:value>
</sv:property>
<sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>cbd43fb6-3530-11e4-8920-164230d1df67</sv:value>
</sv:property>
<sv:property sv:name="className" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>com.pb.viewpoint.common.model.Component</sv:value>
</sv:property>
<sv:property sv:name="jcr:title" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>Viewpoint</sv:value>
</sv:property>
<sv:property sv:name="pb:licensed" sv:type="Boolean">
    <sv:value>true</sv:value>
</sv:property>
<sv:node sv:name="pb:roles" jcr:primaryType="pb:role">
    <sv:node sv:name="Community Administrator">
        <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
            <sv:value>pb:role</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
            <sv:value>cbd441d2-3530-11e4-8920-164230d1df67</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="className" sv:type="String">
            <sv:value>com.pb.viewpoint.common.model.Role</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="jcr:title" sv:type="String">
            <sv:value>Community Administrator</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="pb:nameDisplayKey" sv:type="String">
            <sv:value>roleNameKey.CommunityAdministrator</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="pb:categoryDisplayKey" sv:type="String">
            <sv:value>categoryKey.Administrative</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="pb:category" sv:type="String">
            <sv:value>Administrative</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="pb:type" sv:type="String">
            <sv:value>ADMINISTRATOR</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:node sv:name="pb:entitlements" jcr:primaryType="pb:entitlement">
            <sv:node sv:name="VIEWPOINT_LIST_ROLE_MAPPINGS">
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                    <sv:value>pb:entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>cbd44308-3530-11e4-8920-164230d1df67</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="className" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>com.pb.viewpoint.common.model.Entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:title" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>VIEWPOINT_LIST_ROLE_MAPPINGS</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
            </sv:node>
            <sv:node sv:name="VIEWPOINT_UPDATE_ROLE_MAPPINGS">
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                    <sv:value>pb:entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>cbd44434-3530-11e4-8920-164230d1df67</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="className" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>com.pb.viewpoint.common.model.Entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:title" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>VIEWPOINT_UPDATE_ROLE_MAPPINGS</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
            </sv:node>
            <sv:node sv:name="VIEWPOINT_LIST_COMMUNITIES">
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                    <sv:value>pb:entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>85438386-343b-11e4-99ba-164230d1df67</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="className" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>com.pb.viewpoint.common.model.Entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:title" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>VIEWPOINT_LIST_COMMUNITIES</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
            </sv:node>
            <sv:node sv:name="VIEWPOINT_UPDATE_COMMUNITIES">
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                    <sv:value>pb:entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>854385fc-343b-11e4-99ba-164230d1df67</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="className" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>com.pb.viewpoint.common.model.Entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:title" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>VIEWPOINT_UPDATE_COMMUNITIES</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
            </sv:node>
            <sv:node sv:name="VIEWPOINT_VIEW_COMMUNITY_TO_VAULT_DATABASE_MAPPINGS">
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                    <sv:value>pb:entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>cbd4465a-3530-11e4-8920-164230d1df67</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="className" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>com.pb.viewpoint.common.model.Entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:title" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>VIEWPOINT_VIEW_COMMUNITY_TO_VAULT_DATABASE_MAPPINGS</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
            </sv:node>
            <sv:node sv:name="VIEWPOINT_EDIT_COMMUNITY_TO_VAULT_DATABASE_MAPPINGS">
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                    <sv:value>pb:entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>cbd4484e-3530-11e4-8920-164230d1df67</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="className" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>com.pb.viewpoint.common.model.Entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:title" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>VIEWPOINT_EDIT_COMMUNITY_TO_VAULT_DATABASE_MAPPINGS</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
            </sv:node>
            <sv:node sv:name="VIEWPOINT_VIEW_ENGAGEONE_SERVER">
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                    <sv:value>pb:entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>8543873c-343b-11e4-99ba-164230d1df67</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="className" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>com.pb.viewpoint.common.model.Entitlement</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
                <sv:property sv:name="jcr:title" sv:type="String">
                    <sv:value>VIEWPOINT_VIEW_ENGAGEONE_SERVER</sv:value>
                </sv:property>
            </sv:node>
        </sv:node>
    </sv:node>
</sv:node>
```

Is there any reason for the strange behaviour, am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone reason I don't see this behaviour in Database backed Jackrabbit.

I have only observed the behaviour in InMemory Jackrabbit which stopped me writting my tests